# psexec not recognized

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am working on a Microsoft Server 2008 machine.  For some reason, the command "psexec" is not working from powershell on this 1 machine.

When I try to run it I get this:

```
PS C:\> psexec
The term 'psexec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ psexec <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (psexec:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\>
```

It is running powershell 2.0.  I found this out by doing:

```
PS C:\> $Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1


PS C:\>
```

Any thoughts?  I need this command and I'd really prefer not to use a "work around".

Comment: You have downloaded & installed psexec, right?

Comment: Woops... I didn't realize it wasn't a standard utility that came with powershell.  This is what happens when you company's administrators do too much work for you :)

Thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completing the Answer:

You must need to download PSEXEC from the link below and keep in path the launch from Powershell or any Command prompt:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: Sorry to hijack, but since this is recent enough, is psexec not the standard Powershell that comes with Vista and Win 7? What is the different? What is "ps" in psexec?

Comment: PsExec and PowerShell are totally different things. I believe only Mark Russinovich can give what is "Ps" in "PsExec" however it is just related with Process and "ps" is just representing it.

Comment: Learn more about PsExec here: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec